# Xcode 5 - iOS7 UITableView changes

Tags: uitableview, calayer, ios7, xcode5

since the iOS7 will be released in an about a week, I am making some changes on the current version of my app. I have noticed that UITableViews hadn't changed a lot, but there is one think that i can't understand.

I am using grouped UITableViews, which look on the screen like the plain ones but only of course separated, without round corners. Since I have seen that apple has changed the corners of the grouped tableview in the iOS7 Settings, how can i do that?

I have tried with layer shapes bezier paths, but none of these worked. Any advice how can i make those corners round?

Comment: iOS7 is still under NDA.  Try the apple developer forums.

Comment: @NicholasHart, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94465/should-moderators-enforce-ndas-for-software-vendors

Comment: @peko That doesn't mean it's not breaking the NDA to ask or answer. Just that it's not up to Stack Overflow to moderate such questions and answers. Violations are up to people who ask and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try doing something like this:

```
#define inset 20.0f

- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    // To bring about the rounded corner radius in iOS7
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
    {
        frame.origin.x += inset;
        frame.size.width -= 2 * inset;
        [super setFrame:frame];

        super.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
        [super setClipsToBounds:YES];
    }
}
```

Put this inside your custom `UITableViewCell` class.

Answer (score 0):

The 'full width' is a default by iOS7 in grouped UITableView, For the settings like, you need to do some kind of tweak by your self, you can a put background for the table cells and a clear color background for the table.